# JPA @NamedNativeQuery sql with dynamic orderby and column name

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, named-query

This is my NamedNativeQuery:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ROWNUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CMSSCODE DESC) AS EL_ROWNM ,
CMSSCODE , CMSSDESC FROM tableName d WHERE CMSPCODE = ? ) a
WHERE a.EL_ROWNM    < ? and a.EL_ROWNM > ?
```

I need to create in a dynamic way the order by, so my sql will be somthing like:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ROWNUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ? ?) ....
```

so in the first parameter `?` I will use the column name i get from the user and in the second parameter `?` I will use `ASC` or `DESC` according to what I get from the user.

How is it possible to make a dynamic sorting in the NamedNativeQuery ?

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not.

Use a dynamic query instead of a named query.